# Program stopped working

Tags: c, codeblocks

```
#include<stdlib.h>

#include<stdio.h>

#include<conio.h>

#include<dos.h>

#include<windows.h>


int main(){

    int iCount=1;

    int min=999999;

    int max=0;

    int iSum;

    int iAVG=0;

    int iValue;

    system("color 97");

    for(iCount=1;iCount<36;iCount++){

        system("cls");

        SetConsoleTitle("chairs");

        printf("\t\tCHAIR VALUES\n\n");

        printf("\nPlease enter the value of chair#: %d.\n>>", iCount);

        scanf("%d",iValue);

        iSum+=iValue;

        if(iValue<min){

            min==iValue;
        }

        if(iValue>max){

            max==iValue;
        }

        printf("\n\nThe minimum and maximum values entered are:\nminimum  value>>%d\nmaximum 

            value>>%d", min, max);
        getche();

    }

    (iAVG=iSum/iCount);

    printf("\n\nThe average value of the entered chairs is: %d", iAVG);

    getche();

    system("cls");

    printf("\t\t\nGOODBYE USER!");

}
```

I wrote this code, a c question. I compiled it within codeblocks, it was successfully compiled and executed. However, when i entered the first chair value, it says that"chairs.exe has stopped working. Im here trying to see what might have lead to this problem. Any can give me a helping hand?

Comment: I wrote this code and compiled it in codeblocks 10.05, the program runned. However after i enter the first chair value, the program receives an error that says "chairs.exe stopped working". Im here looking at the code and trying to solve the issue. Any reason as to why the program might have this problem?

Comment: SORRY ABOUT POSTING IT LIKE THIS!

Comment: I fixed your formatting. Please edit your post to include the question part.

Comment: dont worry about the includes, those are just the libraries i used.

Comment: Thank you Zev Eisenberg.

Comment: Modern compilers tend to warn about the mismatch in scanf/printf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to add '&' in `scanf`

```
 scanf("%d",iValue);
```

Should be

```
 scanf("%d",&iValue);    //<--- Notice '&'
```

And as pointed out by "Zev Eisenberg" in comments.

```
min = iValue //<-- Make sure you are using assignment operator here.
```

Comment: You also have equality comparisons that should probably be assignments. `min==iValue;` should be `min = iValue`. I compiled your code with Clang, which warned me about this issue.

Comment: I see, lol I can't believe I missed out the ampersand and the assignment statements. I also edited back the code, i took the source code line "printf("\n\nThe minimum and maximum values entered are:\nminimum value>>%d\nmaximum value>>%d", min, max);" and place it outside the for-loop, so that it would print the minimum and maximum values one time. Im still learning about C programming at the High school level and I like to practice by writing some simple code sometimes. Again sorry about the poor editing I did. Im new to this website.